# how to use a repeater in a slider

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I want to use repeater in a slider with the following code style. I used 2 repeater for active items and the rest of the items. in each page of slider I have 6 picture. when I have more that 12 picture my problem is started (the content of the second repeater is shown in more than one row)... I have no idea how to handle it... consider that I can not use a literal and generate the slider code in code behind because I have to use asp controls in repeater and I don't want to use more than 2 repeater because I don't know how much data I have. (consider that each 6 item is placed in a div with `item` class.

```
    <%--Start Slider--%>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="container  span12">
                <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide">
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <div class="row text-center">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rpSliderActive" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <!-- ITEM-->
                                        <div class="span2">
                                            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                                                <img src='<%# Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString().Replace("~", "../..") %>'>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6><%# Eval("PrintTemplate_Desc") %></h6>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class="btn btn-large btn-block"
                                                OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
                                                ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                infoprperty='<%# string.Format("{0};{1}",Eval("PrintTemplate_ID").ToString(),Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString()) %>'>انتخاب »</asp:LinkButton>

                                            <%--<a id="A1" class="btn btn-large btn-block" infoprperty="7;~/assets/img/LetterTemplates/02-2014108123656618.png" 
                                                href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rpSliderActive$ctl00$LinkButton1','')">انتخاب »</a>--%>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- ITEM-->
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlSliderRest1" class="item" runat="server">
                            <div class="row text-center">

                                <asp:Repeater ID="rpSliderRest1" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <!-- ITEM-->
                                        <div class="span2">
                                            <div class="thumbnail product-item">
                                                <img src='<%# Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString().Replace("~", "../..") %>'>
                                            </div>
                                            <h6><%# Eval("PrintTemplate_Desc") %></h6>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class="btn btn-large btn-block" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"  ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                infoprperty='<%# string.Format("{0};{1}",Eval("PrintTemplate_ID").ToString(),Eval("PrintTemplate_URL").ToString()) %>'>انتخاب »</asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- ITEM-->
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>

                            </div>
                        </asp:Panel>                                                       
                    </div>
                    <!-- /INNER-->
                    <!-- Carousel nav -->
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel2" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%--End Slider--%>
```

Comment: What kind of problem are you facing while using more than 6 images?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="slideshow" data-transition="crossfade" data-loop="true" data-skip="false">
    <ul class="carousel">
        <asp:Repeater ID="gallery" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <li class="slide">
                    <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "ImageUrl") %>' alt="" width="440" height="200" />
                </li>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: AS you see I know how to use a repeater and as I described my problem is how to use multiple repeaters in such sliders. at the end I used rotator control of telerik component.